# Conditional probability of a binary signal conditioned on a continuous observation

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference, noise

Let K a Bernoulli Random Variable with parameter 0.1 (p(K=1) = 0.1).

Let X = K + W where W is a noise, a standard Normal variable.

We want to find p(K = 0 | X = 0.5).  I reason as follows:

Using the Bayes rule:

[image]

In the conditional Universe of K = k, X is the sum of a standard Normal variable and a constant k.  Therefore it is a Normal variable N(k, 1). Therefore we have:

[image]

Do you agree?

Comment: If W is N(0,1) then X can be any value.  What is the point of having X? Without considering X, P(K=0)=0.9 anyway.

Comment: X can not be any value.  It will be the value of Signal K (0 or 1) plus a noise.  So we have a noisy observation, which in principle and in general is better than having absolutely no information about the state of K and rely purely on its prior.  Given a value of X we can make inferences about the probability that K has a value that are improved over the prior.  However in the case that X = 0.5 it seems that we revert to the prior due to the symmetry ( x = 1 - x).  Anyway, my question is the derivation is correct.

Comment: Not if it has a N(0,i) term added to K since a N(0,1) random variable catake on any real value between - infinity to + infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct.

Since the conditional densities of $X$ given $K=k$ are $N(k,1)$ $k = 0,1$, they have the same numerical value $\alpha$ at $x = 0.5$, and so $f_X(x)$, the *unconditional* distribution of $X$, being the weighted sum $0.9f_{X\mid K=0}(x\mid K=0)+ 0.1f_{X\mid K=1}(x\mid K=1)$, also has value $0.9\alpha + 0.1\alpha = \alpha$ at $x=0.5$. Hence, the *a posteriori* probability of the event $\{K=0\}$ when it is observed that $X$ had value $0.5$ is the same as the *a priori* probability of the event $\{K=0\}$. For *all other* possible observed values of $X$, $f_{X\mid K=0}(x\mid K=0) \neq f_{X\mid K=1}(x\mid K=1)$, and the *a posteriori* probability of the event $\{K=0\}$ is different from the *a priori* probability of the event $\{K=0\}$.

The *a posteriori* probability of the event $\{K=0\}$ is a continuous decreasing function of $x, x\in \mathbb R$, where $x$ is the observed value of $X$, decreasing from a limiting value of $1$ at $-\infty$ to a limiting value of $0$ as $x \to \infty$. Thus, there must some $x$ for which this *a posteriori* probability equals the *a priori* probability, and in this problem, this equality occurs at $x=0.5$ regardless of the choice of value for the *a priori* probability in $(0,1)$.